# Updating and Inserting mysql records in one button using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to Update and Insert records in a MySQL database, I can do both in separate buttons but I want to do both queries from a single button.
I want to do something like:
If the ID (which is primary key) = Something then 
update, else insert, but I can't figure out what I can base that off. Ill include some of my code below.

INSERTING

```
Private Function saveCustomer()
    Dim command As MySqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, surname, house_number, street, suburb, state, phone, mobile, work, email, notes) VALUES (@first_name, @surname, @housenumber, @street, @suburb, @state, @phone, @mobile, @work, @email, @notes)"
    Try
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()

        End If
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", txtFirstName.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtSurname.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@housenumber", txtHouseNo.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", txtStreet.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", txtSuburb.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", cboState.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtMobile.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work", txtWork.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", txtNotes.Text)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Contact Saved Sucessfully")
        Return True
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Return False
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        command.Dispose()
    End Try

End Function
```

UPDATING

```
Private Sub updateContact()
    Dim command As MySqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim query As String = "UPDATE contacts SET first_name=@first_name, surname=@surname, house_number=@housenumber, street=@street, suburb=@suburb, state=@state, phone=@phone, mobile=@mobile, work=@work, email=@email, notes=@notes WHERE id= '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text & "'"

    Try
        connection.Open()

        command = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", txtFirstName.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtSurname.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@housenumber", txtHouseNo.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", txtStreet.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", txtSuburb.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", cboState.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtMobile.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work", txtWork.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", txtNotes.Text)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Contact Updated Successfully")

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        command.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

AND THIS POPULATES MY LISTVIEW FROM THE DATABASE

```
Private Sub loadcontacts() 
    Dim command As MySqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim listquery As String = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY id"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing

    Try
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If

        command = New MySqlCommand(listquery, connection)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        command.CommandText = listquery

        With ListView1
            .Columns.Add("Name", 220, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

        End With


        While reader.Read
            Dim ls As New ListViewItem(reader.Item("first_name").ToString() & " " & reader.Item("surname").ToString)
            ls.SubItems.Add(reader.Item("id").ToString)
            ListView1.Items.Add(ls)

        End While

    Catch ex As MySqlException
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        command.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

I still can't work it out, I'm cheating by including a text box and having it read the id, then i tell it to save ifs it's empty. I would prefer to do it correctly so if anyone can chime in I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It has been ages since I worked with VB so I'm sure the syntax is a bit off.  Anyone feel free to edit as needed.

In your button click event handler

```
If LEN(ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text) > 0 Then
    updateContact()
Else
    saveCustomer()
End If
```

Note I assume here that the ID is set in

```
ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text
```

and that, if the record being edited is new, this will evaluate to an empty string.  If that assumption is wrong, you'll have to share how you know whether or not an ID is available for the insert/update.

**UPDATE**

> it crashes if I don't select a record before I try to create a new record

In that case, rather than checking

```
ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text
```

you should check whether ListView1 has any focused items.

```
If ListView1.FocusedItem <> NULL Then
    updateContact()
Else
    saveCustomer()
End If
```

Comment: Code updates but doesn't save, and it crashes if I don't select a record before I try to create a new record

Comment: Ok first of all it tells me that NULL is no longer supported so I guess you used to use it in an older version haha. So Instead I put:

    If ListView1.FocusedItem.Text <> "" Then
            updateContact() Else SaveCustomer() which gives me the same results, only updates.

Comment: The MSDN documentation states that null will be returned if there is no focused item.  I'm not sure how that translates into VB.Net https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.focuseditem(v=vs.110).aspx